Unity UI Text Component Updating in Inspector But Not Displaying on Screen
I'm working on a Unity project where I'm using Azure Cognitive Services for speech recognition. I can see that the recognized speech text is correctly updated in the Inspector under the Text component, but the changes do not appear on the screen during gameplay.
I'm using a Text component within a Canvas to display recognized speech text. I update the text using a script called DisplaySpeechRecognition:
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class DisplaySpeechRecognition : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text recognizedText;

    private void Start()
    {
        if (recognizedText != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Text component is assigned successfully.");
            recognizedText.text = "Say something...";
            Canvas.ForceUpdateCanvases();
            Debug.Log("Initial text set to: 'Say something...'");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("Text component is not assigned in the Inspector.");
        }
    }

    public void UpdateRecognizedText(string recognizedSpeech)
    {
        if (recognizedText != null)
        {
            recognizedText.text = recognizedSpeech;
            Canvas.ForceUpdateCanvases();
            Debug.Log("Text updated to: " + recognizedSpeech);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("Text component is not assigned.");
        }
    }
}


Debugging Results:
The text  component is correctly assigned (Debug.Log confirms this).
The initial text ("Say something...") is set correctly and is visible on the screen.
The recognized speech text is successfully captured and updates in the Inspector but is not displayed on the UI during gameplay.
Question:
Why is the Text component updating correctly in the Inspector but not displaying the changes on the screen during runtime? How can I fix this issue so the recognized speech text is visible on the UI in real-time?


Maybe dumb question but are you sure you are looking at the correct text instance? Also in general you don't have to manually call Canvas.ForceUpdateCanvases this will happen anyway. And also in general Text is a bit legacy and you should rather use TextMeshProUGUI

Also something that could be going wrong: is this method being called from a background thread or async Task? Most of Unity API doesn't "allow" this so you have to ensure that it is on the main thread .. just guessing here that the speech recognition library you use might dispatch your callback asynchronously

If he's using this library, there are locks in place to make sure the new message has been read in Update.
PS: I see RecognizedHandler from the console is indeed part of this package.

@NPatch if it is like the sample you linked then the locks are not there but you have to put them there if you want to use them. My guess is OP is directly calling this UpdateRecognizedText from the callback which won't work.. also not with a lock. You'll have to ensure the callback is dispatched to the main thread .. e.g. using MainThreadDispatcher (basically a ConcurrentQueue which is worked of in Update)

Yes, all the while the sample is just using the locks to change a variable from Update which is in unity's main thread, just like you said.
